# rosbag Python API not reading messages

Tags: ros, python, ros-melodic, rosbag, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm trying to read several topics using the `rosbag` Python API. However, I'm getting no message back at all. I can call `rosbag.get_start_time()` and `rosbag.get_end_time()`, and they give the correct values. Here's my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import rosbag
import tf2_ros
import genpy
import os


class RGBDTester:
    def __init__(self):
        # input/output paths
        bag_file_path = 'test2.bag'

        # image topics with CompressedImage
        self.topic_rgb = '/camera/rgb/image_raw'
        self.topic_depth = '/camera/depth_registered/image_raw'
        # camera intrinsics with CameraInfo
        self.topic_ci = '/camera/rgb/camera_info'

        self.topics_tf = ["/tf", "/tf_static"]

        self.topics = [self.topic_rgb, self.topic_depth, self.topic_ci]

        bag_file_path = os.path.expanduser(bag_file_path)
        print("reading:", bag_file_path)
        self.bag = rosbag.Bag(bag_file_path, mode='r')
        print("duration:", self.bag.get_end_time()-self.bag.get_start_time(),"s")

        ref_times = []

        # fill the tf buffer
        # maximum duration to cache all transformations
        # https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/356
        time_max = genpy.Duration(secs=pow(2, 31) - 1)
        tf_buffer = tf2_ros.Buffer(cache_time=time_max)

        for topic, msg, t in self.bag.read_messages(topics=self.topics_tf):
            for transf in msg.transforms:
                tf_buffer.set_transform(transf, "tester")

        topic_times = dict()
        for t in self.topics:
            topic_times[t] = []
        full_jnt_values = dict() # store first (oldest) joint values of complete set
        for topic, msg, t in self.bag.read_messages(topics=self.topics):            
            topic_times[topic].append(msg.header.stamp)


        if len(topic_times[self.topic_rgb])==0:
            print("NO colour images. Check that topic '"+self.topic_rgb+"' is present in bag file!")
        if len(topic_times[self.topic_depth]) == 0:
            print("NO depth images. Check that topic '"+self.topic_depth+"' is present in bag file!")

        # remove topics with no messages
        [topic_times.pop(top, None) for top in topic_times.keys() if len(topic_times[top]) == 0]

        if not topic_times:
            bag_topics = self.bag.get_type_and_topic_info().topics
            print("Found no messages on any of the given topics.")
            print("Valid topics are:", bag_topics.keys())
            print("Given topics are:", self.topics)


        camera_info = None
        for topic, msg, t in self.bag.read_messages(topics=[self.topic_ci]):
            camera_info = msg

        if camera_info is None:
            raise Exception("No CameraInfo message received!")


    def __del__(self):
        # close log file
        if hasattr(self, 'bag'):
            self.bag.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    RGBDTester()
```

The output I get is the following:

```
reading: test2.bag
duration: 4.97503685951 s
NO colour images. Check that topic '/camera/rgb/image_raw' is present in bag file!
NO depth images. Check that topic '/camera/depth_registered/image_raw' is present in bag file!
Found no messages on any of the given topics.
Valid topics are: ['camera/depth_registered/camera_info', 'camera/rgb/image_raw', 'camera/depth_registered/image_raw', 'tf_static', 'camera/rgb/camera_info']
Given topics are: ['/camera/rgb/image_raw', '/camera/depth_registered/image_raw', '/camera/rgb/camera_info']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mwell/catkin_ws/src/rgbd_export/src/test.py", line 81, in <module>
    RGBDTester()
  File "/home/mwell/catkin_ws/src/rgbd_export/src/test.py", line 71, in __init__
    raise Exception("No CameraInfo message received!")
Exception: No CameraInfo message received!
```

As you can see, no message is received at all. Here's the [rosbag file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oV5Rq9A7ei8JmZVpepg2ibprpWXuwtFD/view?usp=sharing). Anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333143/rosbag-python-api-not-reading-messages/) by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2019-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note the absence of the first `/` on the topics in the "valid topics" list:

```
Valid topics are: ['camera/depth_registered/camera_info', 'camera/rgb/image_raw', 'camera/depth_registered/image_raw', 'tf_static', 'camera/rgb/camera_info']
Given topics are: ['/camera/rgb/image_raw', '/camera/depth_registered/image_raw', '/camera/rgb/camera_info']
```

You may want to try without those first `/`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-09-17**:
@gvdhoorn You're so right! Thanks!

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-09-17**:
@gvdhoorn Any idea why the prefix `/` isn't used?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-17**:
Prefixing topic names makes them global names, which makes it impossible/difficult/harder to push them down into namespaces fi.

See also [wiki/Names](http://wiki.ros.org/Names).

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-09-17**:
Interesting. But aren't global (absolute) names/paths usually easier to identify?